# Daily output of user information from SharePoint groups using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, modern-team-site

I'm using Modern experience in SharePoint Online.

I would like to output the user information from SharePoint groups as a CSV file for each SharePoint group every day.
Is it possible to create such a Flow?

I am having trouble with how to make it, so I would appreciate it if you could teach me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps and a sample Power Automate you can use to suit your need.

1. Get all the SPO groups (Id, Title) using [Send an HTTP request to SharePoint]
2. Use [Parse JSON] to convert output (body) from step 1 to easily readable properties
3. Use [Apply to each] to process each **group** and then retrieve **users** for that group by using another [Send an HTTP..]
4. Use another [Apply to each] within the previous one to process each **user**
5. Use [Parse JSON] to convert user object to easily readable properties
6. Store Group Name, User Title and Email in variables and then append those to an array variable
7. Create a CSV table using [Create CSV table] action with the data stored in the array variable

[image]

### Detail 1

[image]

### Detail 2

[image]

**Parse JSON Schema for gorups (Id and Title)**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "__metadata": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "uri": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "Id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "Title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "__metadata",
                            "Id",
                            "Title"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Detail 3

[image]

### Detail 4

[image]

**Schema used in Parse JSON for each user**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "d": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "results": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "Title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "Title",
                            "Email"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate how much you have done for me. You are my Hero.

Comment: I created this Flow but I got error in 2nd Parse to JSON. "InvalidTemplate. row '1'、column '11034' action 'Parse to JSON - User' Unable to process template language expression in input : 'Required property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'"

Comment: Before you add [Parse JSON], can you add a [Compose] after [Send an HTTP..]? Use [body] as an input to [Compose]. Are you getting any user for that particular group?

Comment: Hi Matiur, I was getting an error because I specified the wrong body in [Parse JSON]. But now it works fine thanks to you.

Comment: Hi Matiur, An error occurred when the number of arrayUsers exceeded 5000. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting the error when the flow retrieves users by a particular group id? If so, it's a classic SharePoint issue (5K limitation). In that case, you have to use another filter condition to get the users. However, if the error occurs during looping users in arrayUsers, then it might be a different issue. You can potentially use two arrays in that case.

Comment: Thank you Matiur, the error occurs during looping users in arrayUsers.